# Divide the date range given by moment js by weeks

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to divide a given date range into months. And I want to separate these months according to weeks. I want to get the date from the start date to the end of the month at 7-day intervals. For example: (Like 15/12/2020, 22/12/2020, 29/12/2020 -newMonth- 05/01/2020)

It is difficult to understand with this explanation. After all I want to create a json like this.

Starting Date: 15/11/2020 - End Date: 20/01/2021

```
[
  {
    "dates": [
      15, // Starting date(15/11/2020)
      22, // 1 week later
      29 // 1 week later
    ],
    "firstDay": "15/11/2020"
  },
    {
    "dates": [
      6,
      13,
      20,
      27
    ],
    "firstDay": "06/12/2020"
  },
  {
    "dates": [
      3,
      10,
      17
    ],
    "firstDay": "03/01/2021"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tricks that you can use to create the array structure you want:

1. Use a `while` loop, which keeps a `current` date that is constantly incremented by 7 days, to be compared against the `end` date. The `current` date should be initialized using the `start` date in the beginning of the loop.
2. To perform the "group by month" in your desired structure, you will need to using an object (which serves as a dictionary). The object will use the `month + year` combination as key, so that if your date ranges span over multiple years you won't collapse months from different years into the same entry.

For each iteration of the `while` loop, you construct the key from the current date, and then check if the key exists in your dictionary. If not, then we can push this object into your dictionary:

```
{
  dates: [currentDate],
  firstDate: currentDate
}
```

If it already exists, then you simply push the date into the `dates` array of the sub-object.

Finally, to convert your dictionary into the array strcuture you wanted, using ES6 [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will work. See proof-of-concept below:

```js
function generateRanges(startDate, endDate) {
  let current = moment(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
  const end = moment(endDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');

  // A dictionary to track unique month+year combinations
  const daysByMonth = {};

  while (current < end) {
    // Construct key based on month+year
    const key = `${current.month()}${current.year()}`;
    const date = current.date();
    
    // If key already exists, then we push into the `dates` array
    if (key in daysByMonth) {
      daysByMonth[key].dates.push(date);
    }
    
    // Otherwise we construct a brand new sub-object
    else {
      daysByMonth[key] = {
        dates: [date],
        
        // Since this is the first time we encounter the key,
        // We can assume this is the earliest/first date of the month
        firstDate: current.format('DD/MM/YYYY')
      }
    }
    
    // At the end of the while loop, increment by a week, rinse and repeat
    current.add(7, 'days');
  }
  
  // Once done, we only want the values in the dictionary
  // We don't need to keep the unique month+year key
  return Object.values(daysByMonth);
}

const range = generateRanges('15/11/2020', '20/01/2021');
console.log(range);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Moment.JS has an API for adding days to a date: the [add](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) function.

In order to build your final object, you would start from your startDate, and add 7 days for each loop iteration until reaching the end date. Like this:

```js
let currentDate = moment(startDate);

while(currentDate < endDate) { // Make sure endDate is also a moment object
  // Add the current date - you will want to adapt this
  dates.push(currentDate.clone()); // Since .add() will mutate the currentDate object, clone the object when adding it to the array so that it's not affected by the add()
  // Prepare for the next iteration
  currentDate.add({days: 7});
}
```

As for month changes, remember the last month for every iteration (use [month](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/)) and create a new object in your final array, then add dates to object instead of the previous one.

*Side note*: Months are zero-indexed in Javascript, which is not the case for the month day ([date](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/))

Comment: You could also use ‘add(7, 'd')’ as a shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with date or datetime is always a good practice to use milliseconds. Also it is space efficient, a long integer = 4kb instead of a Date() object which is 32bytes.

In your case it is very straightforward to convert our dates to milliseconds, find how many weeks are between as integer and then run a loop increment by this iteration.

```
let from = new Date('2020/11/15').getTime();
let to = new Date('2021/01/20').getTime();
let week = 604800000;
let day = 86400000;
let allWeeks = [];
let current =0;

let weeks = (to-from)/day/7

for (i=0; i<weeks; i++){
  allWeeks.push(new Date(from += week).toLocaleDateString())
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(allWeeks))
//["22/11/2020","29/11/2020","06/12/2020","13/12/2020","20/12/2020","27/12/2020","03/01/2021","10/01/2021","17/01/2021","24/01/2021"]
```

Finally you will have a list applicable for JSON to build any logic you prefer.

I hope to pin point a differed approach to your case!